# Toggling Div and img src at the same time

Tags: jquery, razor

I have my Divs toggling ok, but im trying to get the img to toggle at the same time too, so far im not having much look with the image swapping. im using a razor foreach to make the IDs unqiue, so they dont all change images and expand

heres my code:-

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#@quote.First().Quote.QuoteNo-title").click(function () {
            $("#@quote.First().Quote.QuoteNo-quote").toggle(
                  function () {
                      var img = "@quote.First().Quote.QuoteNo-img";
                      if ($(img).attr("src") == "~/Images/minus.png") {
                          $(img).attr("src", "~/Images/plus.png");
                      } else {
                          $(img).attr("src", "~/Images/minus.png");
                      }
                  }
                );
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="quote-title" id="@quote.First().Quote.QuoteNo-title"><img id="@quote.First().Quote.QuoteNo-img" src="~/Images/plus.png" /> @quote.First().Quote.QuoteNo @quote.First().Quote.Date</div>
<div class="quote" id="@quote.First().Quote.QuoteNo-quote">
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: If you put a breakpoint does it goes into the conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#@quote.First().Quote.QuoteNo-title").click(function () {

                      var img = "#@quote.First().Quote.QuoteNo-img";

                      if ($(img).attr("src") == "~/Images/minus.png") {

                          $(img).removeAttr().attr("src", "~/Images/plus.png");

                      } else {

                          $(img).removeAttr().attr("src", "~/Images/minus.png");

                      }

        });
    });
</script>
```